# Installed libpng16-dev, now I can't install elementary-sdk and other dependencies

Tags: release-loki, updates, software-installation, system

I did a sudo apt install libpng16-dev  to upgrade filezilla. but it removed a lot of dependencies.

Now I can't install elementary-sdk and plenty of other depencies, the following error occurs.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elementary-sdk : Depends: libgala-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgranite-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgtk-3-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried fixing broken packaged at the recovery menu but it didn't work. How can I fix this. I am running Loki

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `FileZilla` and `libpng16-dev`, reinstall the SDK, and then install FileZilla via Flatpak:

https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.filezillaproject.Filezilla

Comment: I already did that, I get an error now that says
elementary-sdk : Depends: libgala-dev but it is not going to be installed

I tried installing libgala-deb but it shows me the same error but asking for libmutter.